# return single attributed value via xpath

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpathnavigator

I've got some XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <auth>
    <token>123456</token>
    <perms>write</perms>
    <user nsid="74461753@N03" username="user" fullname="name" />
  </auth>
</rsp>
```

And I'm trying to use XPath to get the value of "token" into a string.  Simple huh. But can I do it?

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load(url)   'gets the XML above.

Dim xmlNav As XPathNavigator

Dim xmlNI As XPathNodeIterator

xmlNav = doc.CreateNavigator()

xmlNI = xmlNav.Select("token")
```

How to I output the "123456" into a variable?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPathNodeIterator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) provides a set of selected nodes that you can iterate over.  There are two problems with your code.

First, your XPath is incorrect - it should be "/rsp/auth/token", not "token".

Secondly, you need to iterate over the collection returned (in this case you're only getting one node).  You can do this one of two ways:

```
xmlNI = xmlNav.Select("/rsp/auth/token")
xmlNI.MoveNext()
Dim selectedNode As XPathNavigator = xmlNI.Current
' value of the node can be accessed by selectedNode.Value
```

Or you can use a For Each loop:

```
For Each node As XPathNavigator In xmlNI
    ' value of the node can be accessed by node.Value
Next
```

If you can use LINQ to XML, this is even simpler (you'll need to add a reference to `System.Xml.Linq` via `Imports System.Xml.Linq`):

```
Dim xml As XElement = XElement.Load(url)

Dim auth As String = xml.Descendants("token").FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `XPathNavigator` necessarily? I got it like this:

```
Dim list As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("rsp/auth/token")
If list IsNot Nothing And list.Count > 0 Then
    Dim myValue As String = list(0).FirstChild.Value
    Console.WriteLine(myValue) 'prints 123456'
End If
```

Comment: nice and simple and true. but i get "Type 'Xml.XmlNodeList' is not defined."

Answer (score 0):

The XmlDocument contains methods to get Elements per XPath.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load(url)

Dim TokenElement As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("auth/token/text()")

If(Not(TokenElement Is Nothing)) Then 'XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(String) can be Nothing if the expression finds no node
    Dim strValue As String = TokenElement.Value
End If
```

Comment: this looks promising however it doesn't pick it up. is auth/token/text()  the correct notation?

Comment: With `doc.DocumentElement` you get the root tag `<rsp />`. Therefore you get the `<token />` value with the given notation. Is it also possible to use `doc.SelectSingleNode("rsp/auth/token/text()")` to get the same result. I prefere the first notation because I haven't to know the name of the root tag.

Comment: My answer gives you only the first appearance of the `<token />` tag. If you want to have all tags in this structure you can loop through all found `<token />` values with `For Each NodeValue As String In doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("auth/token/text()") 'do something with the value Next`.